# Inner join doesn't show all data in sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I made a query in sql server 2008 as bellow for my online book shop :

```
SELECT Packages.packageName
     , Packages.healthStatus
     , Packages.Stock
     , Packages.Description
     , Packages.Image
     , Packages.YearOfPub
     , Packages.Edition
     , updatePackage.price
     , publisher.publisherName
     , writer.writerName
     , translator.translatorName
     , Categories.CategoriesName
     , Packages.packageID
FROM Packages
INNER JOIN updatePackage
     ON Packages.packageID = updatePackage.packageID
INNER JOIN writer
     ON Packages.writerId = writer.writerId
INNER JOIN publisher
     ON Packages.publisherId = publisher.publisherId
INNER JOIN book_translator
     ON Packages.packageID = book_translator.packageID
INNER JOIN translator
     ON book_translator.translatorId = translator.translatorId
INNER JOIN Categories
     ON Packages.CategoriesId = Categories.CategoriesId
```

but when I execute query SQL server return only books(packages) that has one or many translator because some books hasn't translator/s and in other word, package and translator has many to many relation so I break it by two one to many relation.

**EDIT :**

Thanks to Calvin Smith I resolve my problem and change my query to this :

```
SELECT Packages.packageName
     , Packages.healthStatus
     , Packages.Stock
     , Packages.Description
     , Packages.Image
     , Packages.YearOfPub
     , Packages.Edition
     , updatePackage.price
     , publisher.publisherName
     , writer.writerName
     , translator.translatorName
     , Categories.CategoriesName
     , Packages.packageID
FROM Packages
LEFT JOIN updatePackage
     ON Packages.packageID = updatePackage.packageID
LEFT JOIN writer
     ON Packages.writerId = writer.writerId
LEFT JOIN publisher
     ON Packages.publisherId = publisher.publisherId
LEFT JOIN book_translator
     ON Packages.packageID = book_translator.packageID
LEFT JOIN translator
     ON book_translator.translatorId = translator.translatorId
LEFT JOIN Categories
     ON Packages.CategoriesId = Categories.CategoriesId
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want all books whether they have a translator or not. Replace the inner joins with left joins to get the books that have a null translator value.